# Putting values into Map of Map

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to read from the Command Line in java.

Suppose if I am passing these parameters from the command line-

```
TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3
```

Then after reading from the command prompt, `tableNames` list will have all the above three table names.

```
private static List<String> tableNames= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I need to loop through this `tableNames` and put everything in a `ConcurrentHashMap` by loading the corresponding values from the properties file.

So the way I am doing it something like this.

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap< String,
   ConcurrentHashMap< String, String >> tableList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String,
   String >                       databaseDetails = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
prop.load(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
for (String arg : tableNames) {
   String url = (String) prop.get(arg + ".url");
   String user = (String) prop.get(arg + ".user");
   String password = (String) prop.get(arg + ".password");
   String driver = (String) prop.get(arg + ".driver");
   String suffix = (String) prop.get(arg + ".suffix");
   String sql = (String) prop.get(arg + ".sql");
   databaseDetails.put("URL",url);
   databaseDetails.put("USER",user);
   databaseDetails.put("PASSWORD",password);
   databaseDetails.put("DRIVER",driver);
   databaseDetails.put("SUFFIX",suffix);
   databaseDetails.put("SQL",sql);
   tableList.put(arg,databaseDetails);
}
```

I am not sure whether this is the right way to put the values in a Map of Map? Or I can improve this slightly better?

Comment: keep it simple! you can store all keys in a single map, just prefix the keys with "TABLEx."

Comment: Avoid unnecessary casts: prop.getProperty( arg + ".url" );

Comment: +1 for getProperty, I forgot that totally.

Comment: [tag:Unit-of-Work]: Use [tag:enums] as key of your databaseDetails Maps.

Comment: Thanks Rafeel for the suggestion. Yeah it looks like I can enums here. Can you provide me a small example so that I can understand how to use that here in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is move the creation of the databaseDetails map inside the for-loop. At the moment every time through the loop you are overwriting the details you extracted in the previous iteration. Each time you loop, you are collecting a fresh set of databaseDetails, and therefore need a new databaseDetails map to put them in.

Answer (score 1):

This way you will have only one map in the table list. You should create a new databaseDetails map in every iteration. So delete the databaseDetails member variable, instead of use a local variable in the loop.